# What is the maximum view state size limit when using Winter '14 Server-side view state?

Tags: viewstate

I am trying to find information about the pilot Winter '14 feature which introduces server-side view state. Unfortunately at the moment it is not much more than two sentences about the feature availability.

Does this feature relax or remove the 135KB maximum view state limit? If so, what are the pilot feature limits?

[Winter '14 Release Notes](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_winter14_release_notes.pdf) (PDF), Page 239

> **Server-Side View State—Pilot**
>
> Server-side view state maintains a Visualforce page’s view state on the server, instead of sending it back and forth during form submissions and responses. This can reduce the amount of data being transmitted per request, which can improve performance, especially over connections with limited bandwidth or high latency, such as a mobile wireless connection.
>
> This feature is available as a limited pilot. Contact salesforce.com to request inclusion in the pilot program.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I remember from the [Webinar](http://events.developerforce.com/en/events/webinars/winter-14-developer-preview) on this, it did NOT change the maximum size - if just meant it reduced the size of network traffic to maintain state that had to be transferred between browser and server

*Found the link - see minute 19.50...

Comment: You don't happen to have a link to, or know where I can locate, the webinar content do you?

Comment: Just added it to answer...

Comment: To quote Sandeep Bhanot: "That (135KB) size limit still applies." Oh well, back to the incredibly fun attempt-to-reduce-the-internal-viewstate trenches. Thanks for the link!